# CrashLoopBackOff : Back-off restarting failed container for flask application

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, docker-registry

I am a beginner in kubernetes and was trying to deploy my flask application following this guide: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-a-python-flask-app-and-deploy-with-kubernetes-ccc99bbec5dc

I have successfully built a docker image and pushed it to dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app

but am having trouble debugging a pod.
This is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubernetesflaskapp-deploy
  labels:
    app: kubernetesflaskapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubernetesflaskapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubernetesflaskapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetesflaskapp
        image: beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

And this is the description of the pod:

```
Name:         kubernetesflaskapp-deploy-5764bbbd44-8696k
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:   Fri, 20 May 2022 11:26:33 +0100
Labels:       app=kubernetesflaskapp
              pod-template-hash=5764bbbd44
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.12
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.12
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kubernetesflaskapp-deploy-5764bbbd44
Containers:
  kubernetesflaskapp:
    Container ID:   docker://d500dc15e389190670a9273fea1d70e6bd6ab2e7053bd2480d114ad6150830f1
    Image:          beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app@sha256:1bfa98229f55b04f32a6b85d72860886abcc0f17295b14e173151a8e4b0f0334
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 20 May 2022 11:58:38 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 20 May 2022 11:58:38 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  11
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zq8n7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-zq8n7:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  33m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kubernetesflaskapp-deploy-5764bbbd44-8696k to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     33m                    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app" in 14.783413947s
  Normal   Pulled     33m                    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app" in 1.243534487s
  Normal   Pulled     32m                    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app" in 1.373217701s
  Normal   Pulling    32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet            Pulling image "beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app"
  Normal   Created    32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet            Created container kubernetesflaskapp
  Normal   Pulled     32m                    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "beatrix1997/kubernetes_flask_app" in 1.239794774s
  Normal   Started    32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet            Started container kubernetesflaskapp
  Warning  BackOff    3m16s (x138 over 33m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

I am using ubuntu as my OS if it matters at all.
Any help would be appreciated!
Many thanks!

Comment: most likely it's the image's fault you should try to run it locally first directly with docker
`docker run -p 5000:5000 image-name` 
you can verify if its running with `docker ps` or `docker ps -a`  (-a shows even if it has failed to start).
if it is in exited state you can check the logs with `docker logs -f container-id`

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following:

1. Check if your Docker image works in Docker, you can run it with the `run` command, find the official doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
2. If it doesn't work, then you can check what is wrong in your app first.
3. If it does, try checking the readiness and liveness probe, here the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
4. You can find more hints about failing pods [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/determine-reason-pod-failure/)

Answer (score 0):

The error can be due to the issue in the application as the reported reason is "Back-off restarting failed container". Please paste the following logs in the question for further clarification

```
kubectl logs -n <NS> pods <pod-name>
```